# Grid based graph layout

Tags: algorithm, grid, graph

I'm looking for a way to **lay out undirected connected graphs in 2D grids** where each node is placed in its own cell so that no edges will intersect. An example would be to generate a roguelike dungeon with rooms and corridors according to a given graph. Nodes would become rooms, edges would become corridors. Of course all of it would only be possible if the graph is planar.

Another variant of the problem would be using a 3D grid. I don't know if arbitrary graphs could be layed out in 3D without intersections though.

To make things more interesting (i.e. complex) I'd like to minimize the length of the corridors between rooms. And in the 3D case I'd like to minimize the spread along the third axis even more.

Ideas I've considered are:

- Using a force based node positioning preprocess, then clamping node positions to grid cells.
- Searching for a good layout using A* to iteratively place rooms while using corridor length as heuristic.

Both ideas are not very satisfying. The first one does not guarantee a good solution and the second one seems slow. And by slow I mean unpractical, due to the combinatorical complexity of the problem (NP?).

The problem gets even more complicated if we allow special elements like corridor undercrossings that would soften the edge non-intersection constraint.

So my question is: Are there any algorithms/whitepapers/ideas on grid based graph layouting that tackle all or some of these problems?

Comment: Why does it matter if it's slow? Doing it at runtime?

Comment: @Almo I guess it would take forever even on moderate graph sizes.