# Axis aligned graph layout

Tags: graph, layout, procedural-generation

I am trying to generate dungeons for a small project and I decided to take this approach:
1/ each room can open in four directions (North West South and East)
2/ I initialize the algorithm with a single room.
3/ while I need new rooms:
3.1/ I generate a new disconnected room.
3.2/ I pick a already existing room with remaining closed directions and connect the new room to it.

While it's easy to implement, I am trying now to layout those rooms on a minimap.
Rooms are connected by hallways.

The reason it's not trivial is that, from a room R1, you can have a path like this: NESS. This should lead to a room lower (closer to the South) than R1 was if (and only if) R1 has no path E.
If you have a path like this: NESWNESWNESW... (A spiral) you end up with longer hallways at the beginning of the spiral and shorter as you progress into it.

I would like to avoid steering if possible. By that I mean physic-like simulation where I would loop over problematic areas and increase hallways length until there is no more conflicts.
I think there must exist a deterministic algorithm (a recursive one I think).

I think another formulation of the problem would be: how to draw a tree where each node has at most three child so each transition is axis aligned ?
(With a constraint that a transition N goes upward, W goes left etc).

Also, I am aware that dividing the hallways length by two at each step would solve the problem somehow (assuming rooms with no size) but it does not respect the previous mention, that NESS should ends up lower than R1.

Thanks in advance. If it's not clear enough I can post pictures.

P.S.: it may resemble this question [Grid based graph layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499933/grid-based-graph-layout)
(Stackoverflow proposed this topic as I was creating my question)
But it remained unanswered.

Edit: [image: A maze]
Let's use this example.
The numbers show the generation order.
Now, as it's shown here you also have the layout, i.e. the location of each room. It's what I am trying to find.

Let's say we keep growing this maze and we select the room 8 and the direction West (left). As is, it will conflict with 9. But we can increase the length of the hallway between 3 and 2 (or 2 and 0) to solve that.

If we select 7 and west, a solution could be to increase (0,1) but another solution would be to increase (1,7).

If 8 were growing North (up), we would need to increase (0,5) etc.

I hope it's a bit clearer.

Comment: We need the pictures.

Answer (score 0):

- Generate a grid of closed rooms, larger than you ever expect to need.  Each room has a x,y location according to its location in the grid ( col, row )
- Select the room in the center ( colcount/2, rowcount/2 )
- WHILE new rooms needed

  - Select new room adjacent to previously selected room with unselected side room.  Open the side between the old and new rooms.
- Draw the selected rooms at their x,y locations
- Draw the corridors between rooms that have their adjacent sides opened.

Comment: I know this approach and it's the one I usually use, but I want to try something different. I'll post pictures later. I implemented a slightly different approach than the one I describe and got okayish results. I'll post that too.

Comment: Your question asked for an algorithm to layout the rooms as you specified.  The algorithm I described does so.  I have answered your question!

Comment: I edited the post. You didn't answer the question, as you "explore an existing grid" as opposed to the growing I am trying to get.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your comment but it's also not working. It supposes room will be aligned on an axis (you talk about adjacent rooms but I specified they are connected with hallways) but a bunch of cells randomly generated aren't going to be aligned. You also talk about the cell in the center but nothing guarantees a cell will be there.